# How can I display the PE header in IDA

Tags: ida

How can I make IDA display the PE header like in the picture?

please note to the marked areas, the timestamp is converted, the RVA has xref links, and the raw bytes are aligned with the fields.

[image]

when I try to add the IMAGE_NT_HEADERS struct, and set the PE header to the struct, I get this:

[image]

I do not want to use any plugins, only IDA. in the first picture ida recognised automatically the file headers in live debugging of a UPX file.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps that data was defined as a struct by the user? 50% of the time structs are displayed something like that in Ida View, the other 50% they are a list of numbers separated by commas. There is no way to control or predict which view you will get AFAIK. I've been randomly getting one or the other with the same struct all day.